# How to create a matrix like this in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

I have a table like

```
ID    Name
1      11
2      12
3      13
4      14
5      15
6      16
```

I want to create a matrix using this table. Matrix should be like this

```
0   11   12   13   14   15   16  

1   1/6  0    0     0   0    0

2   0   1/6   0     0   0    0

3   0    0    1/6   0   0    0  

4   0    0    0   1/6   0    0

5   0    0    0    0   1/6   0

6   0    0    0     0   0    1/6
```

Where the index of i is quals to j,  i.e  i=j => 1/6  else 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the neatest way, but it will do what you want:

```scala
//Assuming the table consists of pairs
val table: List[(Double, Double)] = 
  List(
    1.0 -> 11.0,
    2.0 -> 12.0,
    3.0 -> 13.0,
    4.0 -> 14.0,
    5.0 -> 15.0,
    6.0 -> 16.0
  )

println(table)

// The following assumes we want the matrix as a List of rows, where each row is a List[Double]

// Get the columns of table
val t1 = table.map(_._1)
val t2 = table.map(_._2)

// Make the first row separately, since it is different from the others
val firstRow = 0.0 :: t2

// Make the other rows - start with value from first column, then the diagonal matrix entries
val otherRows = t1.zipWithIndex.map { case (a, row) =>
  a :: t1.indices.toList.map(i => if (i == row) 1.0/6.0 else 0.0)
}

// Assemble the whole matrix
val matrix = firstRow :: otherRows

// Matrix as List[List[Double]
println(matrix)

// Printed 
println(matrix.map(row => row.map(a => f"$a%.3f").mkString("\t")).mkString("\n"))
```

I've put this code in a [scalafiddle here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/PiSN55B/15)

The final result is:

```
0.000   11.000  12.000  13.000  14.000  15.000  16.000
1.000   0.167   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2.000   0.000   0.167   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
3.000   0.000   0.000   0.167   0.000   0.000   0.000
4.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.167   0.000   0.000
5.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.167   0.000
6.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.167
```

Comment: `Array.ofDim` can also be used to create a multidimensional array, right?
Limitations: only up to five dimensions supported & no of rows and columns should be known before-hand.
eg: `val matrix = Array.ofDim[Double](rowCount, colCount)`
Reference - [Scala Cookbook](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-scala-cookbook)